# Subqueries and multi tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a basic question regarding a problem I faced:

Let's say I have this model with these tables :

```
Food(Quantity, Animal_id)
Race(Race_code, Race_name)
Animal(Animal_id, Race_code)
```

I have been asked to find the total quantity eaten by each race with select query.

(Of course by using SUM function. `Race_name` is also required for the display)

But I don't know to link the attributes of these tables to go from the quantity to the race name (I only know that my reasoning will be like this `Quanity->animal_id->race_code->race_name`). Any help ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables*.  Your question suggests, though, that the answer is a simple `join` with aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a join, doesn't it? Columns that aren't aggregated (`race_name` in this case) have to be put into the `group by` clause.

```
select r.race_name,
      sum(f.quantity) sum_quantity
from race r join animal a on a.race_code = r.race_code
            join food f on f.animal_id = a.animal_id
group by r.race_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery:

```
select race_name ,(select sum(quantity) from food where animal_id in (select animal_id from animal a where r.race_code = a.race_code))
from race r
```