# SQL query without join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following tables

```
Table  food                      Table Race                       Table animal
+------------+--------------+    +------------+--------------+     +------------+--------------+
| Quantity   | animal_id    |    | race_code  | race_name    |     |  animal_id | race_code    |
+------------+--------------+    +------------+--------------+     +------------+--------------+
```

I was asked to calculate the average food quantity for every race (race_name). The challenge here is that I should not use JOIN because we have not studied it yet.
I have written the following query:

```
    select AVG(f.quantity),r.race_name from food f, race r 
    group by r.race_name;
```

but it doesn't work as I want it to be since it returns the same average food quantity for all races. I know I have to use the animal table to link the other 2 but I didn't know how. I should be using subqueries

Answer (score 1):

That question is **exactly** the same as your previous, where you had to use `SUM` (instead of `AVG`). No difference at all.

> Ah, sorry - it wasn't you, but your school colleague, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67357539/subqueries-and-multi-tables)

Saying that you "didn't learn joins", well - what do you call what you posted here, then? That's a **cross join** and will produce Cartesian product, once you fix the error you got by not including non-aggregated column into the `group by` clause and include additional joins required to return desired result.

The "old" syntax is

```
select r.name,
  avg(f.quantity) avg_quantity
from race r, animal a, food f
where a.race_code = r.race_code
  and f.animal_id = a.animal_id
group by r.name;
```

What you "didn't learn yet" does the same, but *looks* differently:

```
from race r join animal a on a.race_code = r.race_code
            join food f on f.animal_id = a.animal_id
```

The rest of the query remains the same.

Nowadays, you should use `JOIN`s to *join* tables, and put *conditions* into the `WHERE` clause. For example, condition would be that you want to calculate averages for donkeys only. As you don't have it, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select race_name ,(select avg(quantity) from food where animal_id in (select animal_id from animal a where r.race_code = a.race_code))
from race r
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Answer (score 0):

You still have to do some matching of related rows. If not explicitly with `JOIN`  you can do it in the `WHERE` clause. Ie something like

```
select AVG(f.quantity),r.race_name
from food f, race r, animal a
where f.animal_id = a.animal_id and a.race_code = r.race_code
group by r.race_name;
```